# How do i create views.py with Django queryset filter to compare Specific value of two different tables in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```html
JOB_TYPE = (
    ('1', "Full time"),
    ('2', "Part time"),
    ('3', "Internship"),
)


class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.CharField(choices=JOB_TYPE, max_length=10)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_date = models.DateTimeField()
    skillRequired1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    skillRequired2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    work_experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    filled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class EmployeeProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.CharField(choices=JOB_TYPE, max_length=10)
    work_experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    emailContact = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    skill1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skill2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skill3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    skill4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    about_me = models.TextField()
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='employeeProfiles', default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} Profile'
```

i have created two database tables 'Job' and other is "employeeProfile".. I want to Compare and match 'title' of both and want to show only those 'title' which is present in Job but not in 'employeeProfile'.These two tables are in two different Models.

Answer (score 0):

i'd try something like that:

(will probably require to have a `default=''` or `blank=True` in the field declaration)

```py
qs = EmployeeProfile.objects.filter(title='').exclude(user__title='')
```

you can resolve relation with the double __

you can also add `null=True` to the title definition to be able to use:

```py
qs = EmployeeProfile.objects.filter(user__title__isnull=False, title__isnull=True)
```

Comment: i am new to django, i didnot get your answer properly. will you tell me a bit more clearly. Thanks in adance. Here is my source code [link](https://github.com/RKarkee/Jobs-Portal)